# excel vba Multiple check boxes

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to collect the status of many Check Boxes in a User form and write X for check box that is in a  False status Or V when it is in True status,
but I always get the run time error when It gets to the line:

```
For Each chk In UserForm1
```

Run-Time error '438': Object Doesn't support this property or method

Here is what I have so far:

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Col As Long
Dim chk As Control
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
'find first empty row in database
iRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1) _
  .End(xlUp).Offset(1, 1).Row
Col = 1
MultiPage1.Value = 1
For Each chk In UserForm1
    If GroupName = Rooms Then
        If (chk.Value) = True Then
            ws.Cells(iRow, Col).Value = V
            Col = Col + 1
        End If
        Else
            ws.Cells(iRow, Col).Value = X
            Col = Col + 1
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Any Suggestions?

Thanks in advance for any help or leads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the loop on the Controls of the UserForm.

`For Each chk In UserForm1.Controls`

Comment: great @Eitan - please mark as answered (green check mark to left of answer).